# Javabean function empty not allowed in expression language?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, el

I'm trying to write a simple page just for testing right now, before adding actual data.

I have an interface that specifies a method isEmpty() which returns a boolean, with the following code in the JSP:

```
<c:if test="${not empty output}">
    <h2>${output.title}</h2>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${output.empty}">
            <h3>No results found.</h3>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <table title="Unique Users Report">
                <tr>
                    <th>Range</th>
                    <th>Number of Unique Users</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Monday<br />10/29/2012</td>
                    <td>1990</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tuesday<br />10/30/2012</td>
                    <td>1000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Wednesday<br />10/31/2012</td>
                    <td>2112</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Thursday<br />11/01/2012</td>
                    <td>2321</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:if>
```

Since output isn't set into the model at this point, I shouldn't even get to this piece of code.  Replacing the line in the test "${output.empty}" with "${not empty output}" allows Tomcat to parse this EL.   However, with the code currently as is, the code fails with the following error (note that output isn't even implemented at this point, so there's nothing in the model):

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/reports/uniqueUsers.jsp(19,3) "${output.empty}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: ${output.empty}
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1186)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:846)
```

So, is the empty property not allowed in EL, or is there something I'm missing?  I'm using Tomcat 6.0.32.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer here:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/464534/JSP/java/JSTL-empty-keyword

Apparently you can use ${bean['empty']} to access this property, which seems dumb, but there it is.